# Td-agent 2x zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, fluentd

I have td-agent on S1 (server 1), on S2 i have zookeeper and kafka and on S3 i have too zookeeper and kafka, 
config of td-agent is

```
type ruby_kafka zookeepers S2:2181,S3:2181 default_topic topic1
```

but when S2 going down my td-agent on S1 don't sending data to zookeeper on S3
td-agent has status [FAILED] `2017-03-28 11:05:10 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:373:rescue in main_process: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error="Broker has not been set."`

Comment: i styll dont have solution :/